# Jquery .height and .width returns wrong numbers on ajax-ed content

Tags: ajax, jquery, height, width

I'm struggling with geting width and height of block, which is loaded via jQuery's AJAX `.load` function.

In my HTML markup I have links:

```
<a href="image.htm" class="image"><img src="galerie_thumb.jpg" /></a>
```

and my JS:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="hidden" style="display: inline-block;" />');
    $('div#hidden').append('<div id="fancy-content" style="display: inline-block;" />');
    $('a.image')
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' .image_wrap';
            $('div#fancy-content').load(url, function () {
                var height = $('#hidden').css('height');
                var width = $('#fancy-content').width();
                console.log(width);
                console.log(height);
            });
        }); 
});
```

So when i trigger the `.click`, AJAX loads the content of `image.htm` just fine. There is one big image and `div` with description. This is appended at end of `body` tag. When I inspect it in DOM inspector, it has `width` and `height` few hudert because of that image.

Problem is, that this `.width()` and `.height()` functions returns nubers like `69` and `32px`. Which are wrong. I even try `.css()` function, but with very same result.

Funny thing is, that if I try it in different browsers, I got different results. In IE9, when I click the `<a>` second time, I even got right results. This is really mystery for me.

The two divs in my code have their meaning, I will use them for Fancybox, but I need correct width and height of that content to do that...

From my research, I found this article: [Can't get ajax - loaded image's height and width via jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686724/cant-get-ajax-loaded-images-height-and-width-via-jquery) which have similar problem, but solutions posted there didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance for every sugestion, how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i see your issue now - thanks for the guidance..

the dimensions reported by your code are correct at the point of execution. See annotations of your code below:

```
$('div#fancy-content').load(url, function () {
    var height = $('#hidden').css('height');
    var width = $('#fancy-content').width();

    // at this point the browser has received the HTML but *has not rendered it* (the browser has to perform a further GET request to acquire the image linked to by the "src" attribute - it doesn't yet know the dimensions of this image)
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
});
```

change your JS to this:

```
function showDimensions($jqueryObject) {
    console.log("width: " + $jqueryObject.width() + " height: " + $jqueryObject.height());
}

$('document').ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="hidden" style="display: inline-block;" />');
    $('div#hidden').append('<div id="fancy-content" style="display: inline-block;" />');
    $('a.image')
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' .image_wrap';
            $('div#fancy-content').load(url);
        }); 
});
```

then modify the appropriate element in your loaded HTML to call `showDimensions` onLoad, e.g.:

```
<div id="theLoadedHtml"><img src="picture.jpg" onload="showDimensions($(this));"/></a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, If you want to digg in my code, here it is: www.lumiart.cz/foto/secret/kuba/jq_height_problem.zip but if I try your code, It's having the same problem. When i alter your function to log .width() into console like this:  $("#content").load("/home/html", function() {
     var height = $('#content').height();
     var width = $('#content').width();
     console.log(height);
     console.log(width);
    });   Actual size in DOM inspector is 420x183px, but Chrome 15 returns 79 and 58 in console, IE9 return 163x1639 and FF return right values... Mystery :)